# Python OGR: NoneType Error only when writing to OpenFileGDB, reading works fine

Tags: python, gdal, arcgis-pro, ogr, file-geodatabase

I have a peculiar situation when trying to write to a .gdb using OGR. I get a NoneType error following any OGR function after ogr.Open() when I specify the data source as writable. From previous questions (e.g., ['NoneType' object has no attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25781/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute)), I have learned that the NoneType error is thrown when the data source cannot be opened, such as when the path is incorrect. However, I am successfully able to open the OpenFileGDB datasource as read-only and retrieve the correct number of layers, per the code below, which makes the me think I have a different problem. What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

```
Python 3.9.16 [MSC v.1931 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> parcel_gdb = r'C:\mypath\mygdb.gdb'
>>> output_gdb = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB").Open(parcel_gdb, 1)
>>> print(output_gdb.GetLayerCount())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(output_gdb.GetLayerCount())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayerCount'
>>>
>>> output_gdb = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB").Open(parcel_gdb, 0)
>>> print(output_gdb.GetLayerCount())
2
>>>
```

Comment: Try [enabling exceptions](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions) and seeing if you get a more descriptive error

Comment: Thanks for the comment, mikewatt. Unfortunately, it does not look like I get any more information from UseExceptions().                                                                  
>>> ogr.UseExceptions()
>>> output_gdb = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB").Open(parcel_gdb, 1)
>>> print(output_gdb.GetLayerCount())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    print(output_gdb.GetLayerCount())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayerCount'

Comment: What version of GDAL? The OpenFileGDB driver only supports writing since GDAL >= 3.6 (released Dec 2022) https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html

Comment: @user2856, thank you, that was it! Apparently I was on GDAL 3.4.0, which was the default version that came with ArcGIS Pro. I installed a new version of Python and GDAL through Conda and using GDAL 3.6.2, I was able to open the .gdb for writing. Happy to mark your answer as correct if you want to write it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GDAL [OpenFileGDB driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html) added write and update support at [GDAL 3.6](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/tag/v3.6.0#:%7E:text=write%20and%20update%20support) (released Dec 2022).

If your version of GDAL is < 3.6 then you can only use GDAL to read FileGDBs with the OpenFileGDB driver.

If you have installed the [Esri FileGDB SDK](https://appsforms.esri.com/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.4) and have a version of GDAL with the [Esri FileGDB](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html) driver included (either built-in or as a plugin) then you can write/update file GDBs with earlier GDAL versions, however, not many GDAL distributions include this driver.